# Lookahead function syntax error (Regex)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

Hey guys I am getting a 'invalid syntax' popping up and it highlights the '?' in my code. The ? is the meta character for the lookahead function but I don't know why it is not working. Here is my code:

```
import os
import re

def main ():

    file = open (os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Assignment 3/motifFinding.txt'))
    data = file.read().split()

    s = data[0] 
    t = data[1]

    x = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(?=t,s)] 

    print (x)

main()
```

Please help!

Thank you very much

P.S. I am using a Mac

Comment: Simple typographical error: You didn't put quotes around your regular expression.

Comment: Hi I put quotes around '?=t' but it is coming up with error, I am not looking for a small t inside the string s. t is a substring of s

Comment: Try the manual: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I did look but I just didnt understand what you meant. person below answered my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to do a lookahead (`'(?=...)'`) using your variable t somehow.  Lookahead groups consist of parenthesis that have a `?=` right after the opening parenthesis.

Remember that strings need to be surrounded by quotes but variables need to be outside of strings.

If `t` represents a regular expression that you're trying to lookahead on, you could put it inside your lookahead group (`'(?=THIS THING)'`) using string concatenation.  Example: `'(?=' + t + ')'`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, that was all I needed to know. I understand the logic of this but I just didn't understand the just 'put quotation marks' around it. This explained it so much and I just tried it with my code and it worked! Thank you very much.